# Spring Data using Entity class name instead of @Table("table_name") in query for Cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data

In a new project I have to use `Cassandra` as persistence layer.

I'm using `Spring Data` repositories to run queries. My entity looks like below

```java
@Table("my_customer")
public class CustomerEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    ....
}
```

When I try to get number of rows in this table using `repository.count()` it throws following exception

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [SELECT count(*) FROM customerentity;]; unconfigured table customerentity; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table customerentity
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraAccessor.translate(CassandraAccessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.translateException(CqlTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:298)
```

It seems like spring is not detecting table name mentioned in `@Table("my_customer")` to run the query. It should be using `my_customer` instead of `customerentity` as table name in query.

Am I doing something wrong? It works perfectly fine with `JPA` repositories for relational database. I have also tried annotating the entity class with `@Entity(name = "my_customer")` with no luck. (I know it would only affect `CQL/JPQL`)

Comment: You're right, it's from `javax.persistence`. It works with the Cassandra annotation, please post the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably importing `@Table` annotation from `javax.persistence`. If you import the same annotation from `org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping`, then you should be fine.